# Mapbox SDK for new versions of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

Happy new year!

What is the procedure to import Mapbox SDK successful in latest versions of Unity (2020+). Are there extra components that need to be installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Unity 2020.3 LTS and when importing the Mapbox package, if you don't need AR tools, you can remove the GoogleARCore, MapboxAR, and UnityARInterface folders and it works fine.

Comment: Ty this worked for me! I was able to run the Mapbox Interactive Map example in Unity after deleting 4 founders relating to AR(UnityARInterface and UnityARKit if I recall). Using Unity: 2020.3.26f1 Personal <DX11>

Comment: Holy Christ Ive been at this for the last 3 hours thinking I've done something wrong. Question... What If I did eventually want to use AR?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Package From [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mapbox-unity-sdk/v1/mapbox-unity-sdk_v2.1.1.unitypackage) and import.
2. In unity, go `Mapbox menu item`, and past your map box key/token.
3. Open an example see from `Mapbox > Examples` and play

Congrats! MapBox installation has completed. For more details info [visit](https://www.mapbox.com/install/unity/) offical docs.

Comment: These steps are clear to me.. what I am asking is whether new versions of Unity are supported somehow. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

New versions of Unity (2019.4 and 2020) are NOT supported.
If you download the package you get all kinds of errors.

Comment: reached out to helpdesk of MapBox but got ZERO reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is true. There are severe issues with Mapbox Unity SDK with Unity 2020. It works fine with Unity 2018.4 LTS version and 2017 LTS version. I think Mapbox SDK is not compatible with ARFoundation that's why whenever your import this SDK in Unity 2020, you get errors in hundreds and thousands of warnings. SO stick with Unity 2018.